# R unique columns or rows incomparables with NA

Tags: r, unique, na

Anyone know if the `incomparables` argument of `unique()` or `duplicated()` has ever been implemented beyond `incomparables=FALSE`?

Maybe I don't understand how it is supposed to work...

Anyway I'm looking for a slick solution to keep only unique columns (or rows) that are identical to another column besides extra `NA`s? I can brute force it using `cor()` for example, but for tens of thousands of columns, this is intractable.

Heres an example, sorry if its a little messy, but I think it illustrates the point.  Make some matrix `z`:

```
z <- matrix(sample(c(1:3, NA), 100, replace=TRUE), 10, 10)
colnames(z) <- paste("c", 1:10, sep="")
rownames(z) <- paste("r",1:10, sep="")
```

lets add a couple duplicate columns with extra `NA`s, and randomize the columns, (that way they aren't always at the end).

```
c3.1 <- z[, 3]
c3.1[sample(1:10, 3)] <- NA
c8.1 <- z[, 8]
c8.1[sample(1:10, 5)] <- NA

z <- cbind(z, c3.1, c8.1)
z <- z[, sample(1:ncol(z))]
```

So I could sort by the number missing, then it would seem as though `duplicated()` or `unique()` would work, but it doesn't like to ignore missing.

```
missing <- apply(z, 2, function(x) {length(which(is.na(x)))})
z.sorted <- z[, order(missing)]

z.sorted[,!duplicated(z.sorted,MARGIN=2)]
unique(z.sorted,MARGIN=2)
```

I figured this is what the `incomparables` argument was specifically for, but it doesn't appear to be implemented yet:

```
z.sorted[,!duplicated(z.sorted,MARGIN=2,incomparables=NA)]
unique(z.sorted,MARGIN=2,incomparables=NA)
```

I know I will likely find a less elegant solution soon enough, I guess I'm more asking about why this hasn't been implemented yet? or if I'm just using it wrong. Seems I run into this quite often, yet I searched around for quite a while without finding answer. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you provide an example output (for a given input)? In case of something like `matrix(c(NA, 1, 2, 2, NA, 2, 2, 3, NA), 3, 3)` which column is considered equal to which after removing `NA`s?

Answer (score 3):

As you suspect, for the `data.frame` and `matrix` methods of `unique`, `incomparables != FALSE` is not yet implemented. It *is* implemented in the default method, which is used for vectors without dims. E.g.:

```
unique(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA), incomparables=2)
## [1]  1  2  2  3 NA

unique(c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, NA, NA, NA), incomparables=NA)
## [1]  1  2  3 NA NA NA
```

Take a look at the source of `unique.matrix` versus `unique.default` (just type the function names into the console and hit `Enter`, or press `F2` in RStudio ro open the source in a new pane).

In your case, you could use `outer` to create a matrix indicating whether particular pairs of rows/columns are the same or not, disregarding `NA`s.

```
same <- outer(seq_len(ncol(z)), seq_len(ncol(z)), 
              Vectorize(function(x, y) all(z[, x]==z[, y], na.rm=TRUE)))

same

##        [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
##  [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##  [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##  [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##  [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##  [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##  [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##  [7,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##  [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
##  [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## [10,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
## [11,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
## [12,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Then, if you want to keep only those columns that are the same as, e.g., the second column (which is column `c8.1` for me - see bottom of this post for the full `z` matrix I used), you can do:

```
z[, same[2, ]] # or, equivalently, z[, same[, 2]]

##     c8.1 c8
## r1     2  2
## r2     1  1
## r3    NA  3
## r4    NA  1
## r5     3  3
## r6    NA  1
## r7     2  2
## r8    NA  1
## r9     3  3
## r10   NA  1
```

To reduce the matrix to the set of columns that is unique (ignoring `NA`), and has the least number of `NA`s, you can then do:

```
z[, unique(sapply(apply(same, 2, which), function(x) 
  x[which.min(colSums(is.na(z))[x])]))]

##      c7 c8 c3 c1 c6 c10 c2 c9 c4
##  r1   2  2  1  2  1   1  1  2 NA
##  r2   3  1  3  1  3  NA  1  2  2
##  r3   2  3  2  3  1  NA  2  1 NA
##  r4   2  1  1  2  2   1  3 NA  2
##  r5  NA  3  2  1  3   2 NA NA  3
##  r6   2  1  2  2  1   1  2  1 NA
##  r7   2  2  2  2 NA   3  1  2  2
##  r8  NA  1  1  3  2  NA  1 NA  1
##  r9   1  3  3  2 NA   2  1 NA  2
## r10  NA  1  1 NA  1   1  1  2  3
```

---

For reference, here is the `z` I was working with:

```
    c7 c8.1 c3 c1 c5 c10 c8 c6 c2 c3.1 c9 c4
r1   2    2  1  2  1   1  2  1  1    1  2 NA
r2   3    1  3  1  3  NA  1  3  1    3  2  2
r3   2   NA  2  3  1  NA  3  1  2    2  1 NA
r4   2   NA  1  2 NA   1  1  2  3   NA NA  2
r5  NA    3  2  1  3   2  3  3 NA    2 NA  3
r6   2   NA  2  2  1   1  1  1  2    2  1 NA
r7   2    2  2  2  1   3  2 NA  1    2  2  2
r8  NA   NA  1  3 NA  NA  1  2  1   NA NA  1
r9   1    3  3  2  1   2  3 NA  1   NA NA  2
r10 NA   NA  1 NA NA   1  1  1  1    1  2  3
```

Comment: Thanks @jbaums! I'm not sure I've used `outer()` this way before, and it works great for small(er) numbers of columns.  However the problem blows up exponentially(?) with increasing numbers of columns as `outer()` must produce a square matrix with dimensions equal to the number of columns. I tested it with an n by p matrix of n=500 rows and p=100, 1,000, or 10,000, and got working times of 0.322, 31.585, and 4663.407 seconds, respectively.   I would typically need this capability on 10,000s to 100,000s of columns.  I might have to find another solution...