# filter unique rows ignoring NA

Tags: r

These are my example data:

```
df <- data.frame("x" = c(1,1,2,3,4,NA,NA,6), "y"=c(1,1,6,7,8,9,9,10))

   x  y
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  2  6
4  3  7
5  4  8
6 NA  9
7 NA  9
8  6 10
```

I'd like to get rid of duplicate entries (=rows), but I want to keep entries with at least one NA. As a result, only the second row above should be deleted, while the 7th should be kept. `unique(df, incomparables=NA)` yields an error message.

Comment: of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34625319/4137985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` with `rowSums`

```
df[!duplicated(df) | rowSums(is.na(df)) == 1, ]

#   x  y
#1  1  1
#3  2  6
#4  3  7
#5  4  8
#6 NA  9
#7 NA  9
#8  6 10
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `complete.cases` and `duplicated` to subset `df`.

```
df[!complete.cases(df) | !duplicated(df),]
#   x  y
#1  1  1
#3  2  6
#4  3  7
#5  4  8
#6 NA  9
#7 NA  9
#8  6 10
```